# Comma use in a lengthy compound/complex sentence

Tags: punctuation

I'm confused as to what the appropriate commas would be in this rather lengthy compound sentence. I've added the commas, but somehow it doesn't feel quite correct and seems over-punctuated. Are there any other ways of punctuating this that reduce the number of commas while maintaining the integrity of the sentence?

> On Thursday morning, we looked around the city, and in the afternoon we met Sally, who was already in Vancouver, and the three of us made our way to the farm.

Answer (score -1):

All the commas seem correct to me. However, the problem is that the sentence is pretty bulky, which is more likely the source of your disquiet. It feels like three sentences spliced together (although your use of conjunctions makes it not actually a comma splice.) I'd suggest it would be more impactful broken up.

> We looked around the city on Thursday morning. Later, in the afternoon, we met Sally, who was already in Vancouver. Then the three of us made our way to the farm.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response and suggestions!

Comment: FWIW, I think it is shockingly bad manners to down vote an answer without giving any comment or reason for your down vote. It really doesn't add the the community if you don't offer some insight into the question that I may very well have missed.

Comment: @Shannon if you feel my answer addressed your question, would you mind accepting the answer? There is a checkbox next to it, which you click to make it go green. I just mention it since I know you are a new contributor and you might not be fully familiar with the protocol.